# Solve a tedious system of equations which cannot be expressed in matrix form

Tags: matrices, physics, nonlinear-system, math-software, python

I have two non-linear equations with only two variables which are tedious to solve. I'm having difficulty solving this system, is there anyway to input this into a solver? I tried solving it manually but it becomes too complex.

[Please see this link for equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYotR.png)

Any help would be appreciated, I'm posting it here as a last desperate try to get some hint on how to go about it. Thank you so much.

```
def equations(p):
    x, y = p
    return ((3*(x**2+y**2))**-1*(x*(x**2+y**2+2.25)*np.sinh((4*m.pi*y*m.e4)/466)+3*x*m.cosh((4*m.pi*y*m.e4)/466)+y*(x**2+y**2-2.25)*m.sin((4*m.pi*x*m.e4)/466)+3*y*m.cos((4*m.pi*x*m.e4)/466))-31.176, 6*(x**2+y**2)**-1*((1+x**2+y**2)*((x**2+y**2+2.25)*m.cosh((4*m.pi*y*m.e4)/466)+3*x*m.sinh((4*m.pi*y*m.e4)/466))+(1-x**2-y**2)*((x**2+y**2-2.25)*m.cos((4*m.pi*x*m.e4)/466)-3*y*m.sin((4*m.pi*x*m.e4)/466))                         )-42.35))

x, y =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))

print equations((x, y))
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, you say that $n_2 = 0$, but in both equations there is a factor of $1/n_2$.

Comment: @PhysMath, you are absolutely right. It was an oversight, I have made the correction. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I've had Mathematica chewing on this for hours, and I don't think it's going to go anywhere. To implement a numerical solution, you'll need to provide quite a few more values than you have. Missing values: $R, T, n_0, n_2, \alpha_1, k_2,$ and $\gamma_1.$

Comment: Hello @AdrianKeister. R=0.152, T=0.0272,N0=1,N2=1.5,Alpha1=(2*pi*10^4*k1)/466,k2=0,Gamma1=(2*pi*n1*10^4)/466

Comment: @AdrianKeister Please find the equations here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYotR.png

Comment: I would probably hand it off to Mathematica's `NSolve` or `FindRoot` routine. You can either use Mathematica in the cloud for free, or download and install the Wolfram Engine for Developers (I use this extremely frequently.)

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks a lot for your help. I wanted to know the method in which I can input the above equation as it is very long. Can you please share how you inputted it on Mathematica? Or perhaps share a link for the same. I would try to find the equivalent of these functions on Python.